# Google RSS Reader interface bug while viewing a channel

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface, web-application

Using Google RSS Reader within the Chrome browser, sometimes when I open a channel I get an interface bug as shown in this picture below. Do you know any solution to fix this?

[image]

Comment: What version of Chrome? What OS? What have you tried?

Comment: Windows 7 x64, newest chrome, I try to re-open this channel, but it doesn't help :/ I don't try other browser, couse I don't want to change chrome.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I only tried to change something in reader options, but it doesn't work :/

Comment: Try clearing the browser cache. Try using a different browser. See if you can replicate the problem after logging off and logging on to Reader again. Try **something**.

Comment: Re-installing Google Chrome might solve your problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a list of installed extensions or note that you aren't using any extensions.

Comment: What version of Chrome @piotrek? Open a new tab and enter `about:chrome` and copy out the version. And which channel URL, or do all channels do this?

Comment: My version is 20.0.1132.57 m , every channel have this issue :/ ( I have for example rss from http://www.altdevblogaday.com/ ) Clean cookies, history etc (everything) also don't help :/)

Comment: There is also something strange, bug doesn't occur when I set i channel setting "translate to my language", but I don't want to translate all channels to polish :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why haven't you disabled Avast Webrep extension already, after running Chrome in Incognito mode and then ruling which extension was the cause ?

http://crbug.com/106643

http://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=89462.0

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/reader/u_jtykYVW9M

Comment: Big thx !:D This help :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that a padding-top is present on each line.
Do you happen to use a plugin that ...

- inserts text on top of a line? (automatic translation...)
- overrides CSS rules?
- modifies the user-agent?

There may be a bug in Google Reader's CSS or JavaScript, but since nobody else could reproduce, it must be an artifact and should disappear after a forced refresh (CTRL+F5)

Comment: I try ctrl + f5, but it doesn't work :/ I haven't got any extensions that can modify css settings of site

Answer (score 3):

Run chrome with a new data-dir to test if you can recreate this issue with a blank config:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir=%temp%\chrome_test
```

This will run an instance of Chrome with a blank config, no plugins and default settings.

If this still happens in this clean environment, it may be a Chrome rendering / Google Reader bug, and you should report it as such.

If this blank environment does indeed display the RSS Reader OK, then one of your extensions is messing up. disable them, one at a time, until you cannot recreate the issue.

Comment: Thx for answer, on blank config I have the same result :/ I try on other computer, and there was the same. It looks good on Opera, but I want to use chrome :/.